# Macro not reading data if the file is in excel format (reads only if the file is in csv format)

Tags: vba

There are two files in one folder, the macro should read both files and create another file combining the two.

This is working fine as long as the file format is CSV format.

The problem is, if the file format changes to Excel then it throws a "Subscript out of range" error.

When I check the the file format using the code `ActiveWorkBook.FileFormat`, in both cases (CSV and Excel) it gives a value 52 meaning "this an Excel file".

My Question:  How can I distinguish the format of the file? Somehow I have to make the macro read both files and create the combined file regardless of the file format.

The line `trimmed(i) = Trim(temparray(i - 1))` is where the error occurs.

```
For Each curfile In fileList
    ediType = fileType(curfolder + "\" + curfile)

    Open (curfolder + "\" + curfile) For Input As #1
    flag = True
    Do Until EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, linefromFile

        temparray = Split(linefromFile, vbTab)

        For i = 1 To UBound(trimmed)

            trimmed(i) = Trim(temparray(i - 1))
            Debug.Print "The value of variable X is: " & trimmed(i) & temparray(i - 1)

        Next
```

Comment: Do you understand what this code does? If so, then why do you expect it to be able to read Excel workbooks? If you don't understand the code, then perhaps you should start by trying to understand it e.g. read up on what `Open` and `Line Input` do. Then if you have specific questions about those, you can ask them here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I am using VBA first time so struggling with small things .

Comment: What small things? Please be specific. Right now I think the problem is, you haven't spent the time needed to understand your existing code. Until you do, it's going to be impossible to help you modify it.

Comment: Here is the explanation what the code is actually doing: Open (curfolder + "\" + curfile) For Input As #1 it will enable  I/O to a file : Next is th Do until EOF(1) this is the loop through file until it reaches to the last line, then Line Input #1 is read line into variable linefromFile. this line code is actually working even when the format is xls but something is going wrong before the loop ends .

Comment: How can I check the format of the file and and make the format as csv if it is excel format.  I am trying to tell macro that first check the format of .xls file if it is csv format then continue else first change the format to csv and then continue .What should be the code to do this . In order to do this I tried with this ActiveWorkBook.FileFormat  it gives value =52 in both cases . xls format and csv format , so this code I can not use. Any other code ?

Answer (score 0):

1.You can distinguish the file using the file extension .xls or .csv
2.After doing that you can save the .xls file .csv and use the same code to read. 
I dont think the same code can be used to read an .xls file, there you have to use excel ranges and cells to read

Comment: Well the problem is not with the file extension . So if the file is either .xls/.csv still it works fine . Some how macro is figuring it out whether the format is excel or csv format . To be more specific Below is an example : File1.xls works fine if the format is csv . but again the File1.xls is not working if the format is excel . its kinda confusing . I hope I am not confusing you though .